# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/ws/soap/SOAPFaultException

Tags: spring, kotlin, soap, openapi, feign

```
    implementation("javax.xml.soap:javax.xml.soap-api:1.4.0")
    implementation("jakarta.xml.soap:jakarta.xml.soap-api:2.0.0-RC3")
```

Added both of the dependencies but still getting this error.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate []: Factory method 'api' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/ws/soap/SOAPFaultException
```

I tried adding all dependencies, never worked on SOAP Apis so I'm extremely clueless

Answer (score 0):

According to your error stack ,  i gucess that your project may be lack of some dependency (java xml web service ) , the cause may be that `spring-boot` dependency or `jdk version` has some conflict or lack in `pom.xml` .

One of the solution is that make up  the lacking part , try to add the dependency below

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- JAX-WS API -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-ri</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Not sure how you  define your project `spring` or `jdk` version , so i provide a general version ,if it does not  work , you can get into maven central repository find out your specify `spring` version  and then choose one which is close to your project dependency version

Provide more dependency version info  in pom.xml.Particularly, `spring`,`jdk` version , error will be more clear and answer will be more accurate ;